# Assembler warning with gcc warning when placing data in .text

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

When I compile

```
__attribute__((section(".text"))) const int x = 42;
int main(){ return x; }
```

with gcc (works with tinycc and clang), I get

`Warning: ignoring changed section attributes for .text`.

What is the cause of the warning and how can it be eliminated while still keeping the (always readonly) data in `.text`?

Comment: Apparently gcc emits a `.section .text,"a",@progbits` directive instead of just `.section .text`. I don't see any way to avoid it.

Comment: Always a good idea to [Google the error message](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00088.html)

Comment: A better answer to this question is probably - "use clang then".  I can think of few reasons not to prefer clang over gcc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently:

```
__attribute__((section(".text#"))) const int x = 42;
```

Ref: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00088.html  where the answerer explains:

> `__attribute__ ((section(".text")))` will make gcc emits
>   `,"aw",@progbits` after the `.text` to alter the section attributes.
>   If you use: `__attribute__ ((section(".text#")))` (notice the extra
>   `'#'`) this suffix will be commented in the assembly and the warning
>   will disappear

In that case the variable concerned was not `const`, so it was especially ill-advised (as stated by [another responder](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00098.html)) to the same question.  In your case it is a `const`, so the access is `"a"` rather than `"aw"` - still probably ill-advised however.

Comment: Not mine.  Another responder in the same thread does indeed give more sage advice:  https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00098.html

Comment: Yes, here OP already has `const` though. I would assume the intent is locality of the data to the code (probably not relevant to split D/I L1 cache but would affect L2, L3 usage) not just a wrong hack in place of `const` for making the data read-only.

Comment: Yes, I am not responsible for any use this information may be put to!  I just google'd it for him - a tart for rep that's me!

Comment: Nice trick, unfortunately doesn't work for me using GCC 6.3. The '#' at the end is interpreted as part of the section name, and causes this error when I try using `__attribute__((section(".data#")))`:

`/usr/lib/gcc/m68k-elf/6.3.0/../../../../m68k-elf/bin/ld: section .data# LMA [000000000000a390,000000000000a40d] overlaps section .data LMA [000000000000a390,000000000000a3db]`

Answer (score 3):

Apparently gcc emits a `.section .text,"a",@progbits` directive instead of just `.section .text`. I don't see any way to avoid it. However the default linker script usually merges all sections named `.text.*` so you can do something like `__attribute__((section(".text.consts")))` and in the final binary it will be in the `.text` section.

@[Clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168986/clifford) found [a hackish workaround](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00088.html) which involves putting a `#` after the section name so that the assembler considers the rest of the line a comment.

Comment: I think it merges them *after* assembling them individually, so this will change the final output order (moving the consts away from their functions)

Comment: That is true, but was not a requirement in the question :)

Comment: Right. However if OP is trying to put constants in `.text`, the most likely plausible reason is for locality with the code.

Comment: @Clifford: Don't! It's a classic one and somewhat blessed in the sense that gcc has never offered up a preferred alternative to it.

Comment: @R.. Won't a literal constant do that?  `#define x 42`. Not pretty, or type aware, but conventional in C.

Comment: @R.. I changed my mind and deleted my comment - now everyone will wonder what I said!

Comment: @Clifford The code in the question is dumbified. `#define x 42` wouldn't work for a nontrivial structure whose address matters (which motivated the question).

Comment: @PSkocik Fair enough.